# webview cant be refresh using java code android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

i have web view and i try to give the user button to refresh but i cant set that button i try to use this code

the refresher button

```
imgbtr2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageButton imgbtr2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonr2);

            WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.loadUrl("Javascript:window.location.reload(true)"); // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

the webview

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);


    webView.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com/");
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

but it seems like Javascript:window.location.reload(true) its not work .
if i use webView.loadUrl("www.exapml.com"); it will work but this is not refresh this is reload the page i want to use it  only for refresh so it will back to the list Url u was there not reopen the webpage from the first url

one more thing i have one EditText . to give the user to but there url . as long as the webview will not open the url as long it start with http:// how can i add http:// to the EditText and user cant delete that part . he can just only add the rest of the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following change in your code, I tried it and it worked for me

```
WebViewActivity.this.webView.loadUrl("your url ");
```

WebViewActivity is your activity name

```
ImageButton imgbtr2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonr2);

WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

imgbtr2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    WebViewActivity.this.mWebView.loadUrl("your url");
}});
```

For the http:// you can simply insert string "http://" at the beginning of the url you get from EditText like this.

```
urlStringFromEditText.insert(0,"http://");
```

Or give this a try

```
final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

edt.setText("http://");
Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());


edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(!s.toString().contains("http://")){
            edt.setText("http://");
            Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: i change it to webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload(true)");
but still the same its not working :(
for the http:// this is really good ans thanks , but what about if someone enter the hhtp:// again in the EditText , then it will not work , my idea is in the EditText it self will have http:// and the user can write after it www . and he cant delete the http but he can delete what he write

Comment: i didn't understand the first part WebViewActivity.this.webView.loadUrl("your url ");
this will load the url i but , but i want to refresh it not load it

Comment: when i use WebViewActivity.this.webView.loadUrl("your url "); the app cant start

Comment: bro any idea how to refresh it ,, i really need it

Comment: WebViewActivity is the name of the Activity, this should make it clear "public class WebViewActivity extends Activity" I have made edit with full associated code.

Comment: yes , choose as ans .. can i ask u something why webview can not open page like https://vine.co/ is it coz its not end with .com .. and how to make it open all the website .. and when u enter website like Myspace and try to login using Facebook everything will work ok until u finish login it will not show anything after u connect it to ur facebook ,, is it coz of the redirection and if it is how to fix it

Comment: Try implementing webclient :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
webView.reload();
```

Note: It doesn't work if the original query was a WebView.postUrl()

Comment: this will reload the url but not refresh the current url